# IIS Rewrite URL Condition Grouping

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm redirecting my website URLs to mobile with the following conditions:

```xml
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
  <add input="{StaticRedirects:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
```

I want to group these first three conditions together and the last one separately.

Redirect rule must be applied if:

1. `HTTP_USER_AGENT` or `HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent` or `HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA` matches the pattern
2. and `{StaticRedirects:{R:1}}` matches the pattern

Is there any way for grouping these conditions?

**PS:** I have nearly 10 rules. Do I have to write first three conditions for each of my rules or is there any tag for all rules?

Comment: I have the same problem. how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal using the distributive law: 
(A + B)C = AC + BC

Use a concatenation of variables in the condition input. Use a separator that is not expected in any of variable values. In the example below, the `///` sequence is used as a separator:

```xml
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}///{StaticRedirects:{R:1}}"
       pattern="(midp|mobile|phone)///(.+)" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}///{StaticRedirects:{R:1}}"
       pattern="(midp|mobile|phone)///(.+)" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}///{StaticRedirects:{R:1}}"
       pattern="(midp|mobile|phone)///(.+)" />
</conditions>
```